# ASP.NET C# Add items to list from stored proc dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to have my accounts shown like below (In a List)

```
<div id=AccountDiv" class"account-table">

<div class="color-1">
<h3>Account Information</h3>
<ul>
    <li style="text-align: left" >Electric: Austin Energy - 10265</li>
    <li style="text-align: left">Gas: Texas Gas Service - 15754892 </li>
    <li style="text-align: left">Propane: Propane Austin - 577-12</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div>
```

I would like to pull each account information from a database dynamically. I'm new to asp.net so I wrote the below

```
<div id=AccountDiv" class"account-table">
<asp:Panel ID="AccountDiv" runat="server" CssClass="account-table">
<div class="color-1">
<h3>Account Information</h3>
<ul>

</ul>
</div>
<asp:Panel>
<div>
```

This is what I wrote back-end.

```
void PopulateAccountInformation()
    {

        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        da.AddParameter("SiteID", SiteID, DataAccess.SQLDataType.SQLInteger, 4);
        SiteHeader = da.runSPDataSet("GetSiteAccountList");

       for (int i = 0; i < SiteHeader.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Label LabelAccount = new Label();

            LabelAccount.Text = "Account Number: " + SiteHeader.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Account Number"].ToString();
            AccountDiv.Controls.Add(LabelAccount);
            AccountDiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

        }


    }
```

It displays the information like:

Account Number: 3 786 843-7

Account Number: 6 520 325-9

Account Number: 80-000178814-0162499-3

Account Number: 100269408-Swr

Account Number: 100034269

Account Number: 100269408

Which is nice, but How to I write it so it makes a list for each Account?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "a list for each Account"?  Do you mean "a list ITEM for each account"?  Or a separate, embedded list for each account?

Comment: Looking at the markup he is trying to achieve, I think he meant a list item (li) for each account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Literal control to your page like this:

```
<asp:Literal ID="litContent" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Then your function as following (not tested):

```
void PopulateAccountInformation()
{
    DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
    da.AddParameter("SiteID", SiteID, DataAccess.SQLDataType.SQLInteger, 4);
    SiteHeader = da.runSPDataSet("GetSiteAccountList");
    string content = "<ul>";
    for (int i = 0; i < SiteHeader.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
       content +="<li style=\"text-align: left\" >" + SiteHeader.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Account Number"].ToString() + "</li>";

    }
    content += "</ul>";
    this.litContent.Text = content;
}
```

Comment: This worked for what I was trying to do. Easy for me to update the content row as needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a Repeater or DataList control. Those are made to display data, you don't need to manually add controls like you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the asp built-in server control `ListBox`. Like so:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstAccounts" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

Then in your code-behind, add the elements like so:

```
void PopulateAccountInformation()
    {

        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        da.AddParameter("SiteID", SiteID, DataAccess.SQLDataType.SQLInteger, 4);
        SiteHeader = da.runSPDataSet("GetSiteAccountList");

        foreach(DataRow account in SiteHeader.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            this.lstAccounts.Items.Add(new ListItem("Account Number: " + account["Account Number"].ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

Markup:

```
<div id=AccountDiv" class"account-table">
<div class="color-1">
<h3>Account Information</h3>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrAccounts" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <ul>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    Account Number:&nbsp;<%# Eval("Account Number") %>
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </ul>
            </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
void PopulateAccountInformation()
{

    DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
    da.AddParameter("SiteID", SiteID, DataAccess.SQLDataType.SQLInteger, 4);
    SiteHeader = da.runSPDataSet("GetSiteAccountList");

    rptrAccounts.DataSource = SiteHeader.Tables[0];
    rptrAccounts.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: This looks like something I could use. Let me play with it and see how it looks.

Comment: @Zach Sure. Just FYI, the reason I like Repeaters and DataLists is because it helps me keep the markup and logic as distinct as possible. So if I had to change this from ul>li to tr>td, I would just have to change the markup which wouldn't require a compilation.